# permanent image theme setting

Tags: forms, media

Hy,
I'm trying to display an image which has been set in the theme settings. This file should be stored permanently. I'm using drupal 8 and based on the information I found online, this is what I got:

First of all I added the setting to the form with the following code (located in theme-settings.php):

```
function THEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
    if (isset($form_id)) {
        return;
    }

    $form['default_avatar'] = array(
        '#type'          => 'managed_file',
        '#title'         => t('default avatar'),
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('default_avatar'),
        '#description'   => t("The default avatar for users."),
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'THEME_form_system_theme_settings_submit';

    // Get the current theme
    $active_theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getPath();
    $form_state->addBuildInfo('files', $active_theme . '/theme-settings.php');
}
```

Then I use the following submit hook (located in theme-settings.php):

```
function dwagulu_form_system_theme_settings_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
    $image_fid = $form_state->getValue('default_avatar');
    if (count($image_fid) > 0) {
        $image = file_load($image_fid[0]);
        if (is_object($image)) {
            // Check to make sure that the file is set to be permanent.
            if (!$image->isPermanent()) {
                $image->setPermanent();
                $image->save();
                // Add a reference to prevent warnings.
                $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
                $file_usage->add($image, 'dwagulu', 'theme', 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems correct, however, when I add upload an image and save the settings I get the following warnings:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache->loadCachedFormState() (line 157 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache.php).
Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache->loadCachedFormState('form-5FkI3Kf8XhoxscPOAf-slbJ7Nn--ubyPoCQoO5UaQhQ', Object) (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache->getCache('form-5FkI3Kf8XhoxscPOAf-slbJ7Nn--ubyPoCQoO5UaQhQ', Object) (Line: 432)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getCache('form-5FkI3Kf8XhoxscPOAf-slbJ7Nn--ubyPoCQoO5UaQhQ', Object) (Line: 257)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 74)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 139)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 98)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 77)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 628)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'dwagulu_form_system_theme_settings_submit' not found or invalid function name in Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers() (line 111 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter.php).
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 583)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('system_theme_settings', Array, Object) (Line: 314)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 74)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 139)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 98)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 77)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 628)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

This second warning would lead me to believe that the submit function is not correctly loaded, despite the fact that I added it to the build_info of the form_state. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be missing.

Kind regards.

// edit:

I continues experimenting with the code. I moved both functions "alter" and "submit" to the THEME.theme file. Then I changed the build_info to include the THEME.theme file. This removed the warnings and I can see that my code is executed. The file's status is set to permanent. This is good, however, when I ask for the file, the uri is "temporary://default-avatar_2.png" which is not permanent I assume?

Answer (score 2):

By adding an upload location to the form field:

```
$form['default_avatar'] = array(
    '#type'            => 'managed_file',
    '#title'           => t('default avatar'),
    '#default_value'   => theme_get_setting('default_avatar'),
    '#description'     => t("The default avatar for users."),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://'
);
```

the file is no longer uploaded to a temporary url.